# What test should I use to test enrichment of domains in mutation set?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, biostatistics

I have a list of mutations from a certain disease with affected proteins listed.

Proteins have multiple domains, and I'm interested which domains are overrepresented.

Example values:

- Humans have 20000 proteins
- These proteins have 0 or more domains. There are 15000 identified domains in the list. Each domain can be in one or more protein one or more times.
- In total, 19000 proteins have some domains, and the sum of domains in these 19000 is 30000.
- I have a list of 40000 mutations affecting 10000 proteins (one protein can be present multiple times), with a total of 25000 domains (12000 unique).
- Domain X occurs 2800 times in 2500 mutations, in 55 different proteins. In the set of all human proteins, it occurs in 120 times in 100 proteins.

How do I test if domain X is overrepresented in the mutation set? Since domains can occur multiple times in each protein, and each protein can occur multiple times in the results, I'm a little bit confused about how to proceed.

Comment: Are your mutation data domain-specific, or protein-specific? I.e., do you know that a mutation affects a particular domain, or do you only know that it affects a given protein containing the given domain?

Comment: P.S. It is an interesting variant on the question of enrichment analysis in genes and proteins!

Comment: @January I know the precise location of mutation, so it could be called domain-specific. But I'm not as much interested in what domains are hit by mutations particularly often, as I am what kind of domains are overrepresented in the potentially abnormally behaving proteins. The problem is close to GO enrichment, but since those usually deal with sets where each gene is featured either once or not at all, the problem seems slightly different and I'm far from comfortable with it.